# how to remove the gap between subplots and around

Tags: matlab, margins, subplot

I am plotting two subplots (2x1) in one figure. I would like to remove all the spacing between two subplots and remove the xlable and xlabel ticks for the top subplot too. Also, I am trying to remove all the spacing outside the subplot. I try

```
set(gca, 'LooseInset', get(gca,'TightInset'))
```

But it doesn't work. Now I am removing those margins and labels manually, I have 60 figures need to be handled and doing all those manually is time consuming. Any better way to do it? Thanks.

I also try the subtightplot, it helps to reduce all the margins but the xlabel and ylabel are also cut

```
margins=[0 0];
t = 0:0.01:10;
y1 = sin(t);
y2 = cos(t);
h1 = subtightplot(2,1,1, margins);
plot(t, y1);
ystr = {'sin(x)','(dimensionless)'}
hy1 = ylabel(ystr);
set(gca, 'fontsize', 14);
set(hy1, 'fontsize', 14);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', [],'XTick',[])

h2 = subtightplot(2,1,2,margins);
plot(t, y2, 'r-o');
hx2=xlabel('frequency');
hy2=ylabel('amplitude');
set(gca, 'fontsize', 14);
set(hx2, 'fontsize', 14);
set(hy2, 'fontsize', 14);
```

I also try the subplot_tight but it is even worse

Comment: "it helps to reduce all the margins but the xlabel and ylabel are also cut" what does that mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [subplot_tight](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30884-controllable-tight-subplot) or [subtightplot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39664) from the FEX.
to remove all x-tick and labels use:

```
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', [],'XTick',[])
```

in the appropriate subplot...

### **Edit:**

Since you do want to include the labels etc, you can so it using the `position` handle in `axes`:

```
t = 0:0.01:10;
y1 = sin(t);
y2 = cos(t);


left= 0.15;
bottom1=0.5;
bottom2=0.05;
width=0.8;
height=0.45; % which is also bottom1-bottom2

axes('Position',[left bottom1 width height]);
plot(t, y1);
ystr = {'sin(x)','(dimensionless)'}
hy1 = ylabel(ystr);
set(gca, 'fontsize', 14);
set(hy1, 'fontsize', 14);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', [],'XTick',[])


axes('Position',[left bottom2 width height])
plot(t, y2, 'r-o');
hx2=xlabel('frequency');
hy2=ylabel('amplitude');
set(gca, 'fontsize', 14);
set(hx2, 'fontsize', 14);
set(hy2, 'fontsize', 14);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I tried that code but I figure out that if I plot thing in tight margin, the x and y label are partial cut. I have upload a sample code in the original question.

Comment: So you need to rephrase the question... you asked *"to remove all the spacing between two subplots ... Also, I am trying to remove all the spacing outside the subplot"*

Comment: So it seems you need to get down to the level of `position` in the `axes` to get that right.

Comment: It looks much better. Thanks for your help :)