# Plot a big figure with many subfigures in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, subplot

I have to print a large poster, containing a matrix of figures, and it would be very practical for me to let MATLAB arrange them. Unluckily, subplots are displayed to fit a certain figure size, so are tiny and distorted. Instead of fitting the figure size, I would like to fit the paper size of my poster.

I have tried with `set(gcf,'Position'..)`, and also changing papersize, but I still don't see the expected result.

Is there something I can try to let MATLAB use, say, a whole A0 sheet to plot?

Here's my current output:

[image: Current output]

Comment: What went wrong when using subplots? Using this and exporting as esp should provide a good quality print.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove spacing in matlab subplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397956/remove-spacing-in-matlab-subplot)

Comment: Can you edit your post to add a link to an image of how your plot currently looks and describe how you would like it to look?

Comment: I agree with thewaywewalk, Remove spacing in subplot should do the trick here, for your A0 print, you just need to set the position to fit on the A0 such that your image will not be distorted.

Comment: I don't want to remove spaces, just display visible subplots in an A0 sized figure.
I added the figure for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%just a dummy example
r=11;
c=4;
f=figure()
for inx=1:r*c
    subplot(r,c,inx)
    bar(randi(10,4,3))
end
%print it on A0
set(f,'paperunits','centimeter')
set(f,'papersize',[84.1,118.9])
set(f,'paperposition',[0 0 84.1 118.9]);
print(f,'example.pdf','-dpdf','-opengl');
```

If I print such a Plot on A0 everything looks fine. Your screen might be too small, but it fits on a A0 sheet.

Comment: I wonder why the '-opengl' argument makes the difference, I tried removing it and I got back my previous useless result.