# matlab uitable has poor quality when saving pdf

Tags: matlab, pdf, save, matlab-uitable

I'm creating a table to put in an image. when I save a pdf. file (or png for that matter), the plots have nice quality but the table is supper bad (see image 1, a close up). It looks fine on matlab (image2)

How can I overcome this?

[image: pdf image with bad quality]

[image: How it looks like on matlab]

Comment: Try these commands to create the pdf: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29288508/2732801 If it looks good fix the paper size (it prints A0, I assume you want A4 or us letter?)

Comment: @Daniel, it is still bad quality, just like before... The plots are/were good, it's just that table..