# How to save a high-resolution figure in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, save

When I save a figure from MATALB, I'd like the resulting image to have very high resolution so that I can zoom in to see detail in the image. When I use 'File --> Save As' on a figure, the image is not high resolution.

How can I save a figure to a high resolution image in MATLAB?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear as you have contradicted yourself in it. At one point you want to save the zoomed in image but then in the next you don't you want it to save the entire image?

Comment: [you can render figures in a resolution larger than your screen resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280919/plot-a-big-figure-with-many-subfigures-in-matlab/29288508)

Comment: @IKavanagh I want to be able to save an image which allows me to zoom in without losing the resolution/detail, similiar to what the MATLAB fig allows you to do. When I save it as png/jpg/tiff etc. and try to zoom in, it loses the resolution/ability to resolve between detail.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can specify a desired resolution to save the image, either from the command line or from the File menu.

**Command line:**
Using `print`, just include the option `-r###`, where `###` if the resolution you want. Usually 300 dots-per-inch (dpi) is plenty high enough resolution for my purposes, but feel free to go higher if needed. Obviously the higher the dpi the larger the image file size will be.

```
print(gcf,'foo.png','-dpng','-r300');         *// 300 dpi
```

Check out the [MATLAB print documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html?refresh=true) to see all the print options you can adjust like this.

**File menu:** Or using 'File -> Export Setup...', on the left select 'Rendering', then adjust the 'Resolution (dpi)'. By default it set to 'auto'.

As with the command line, there are many printing options you can adjust in the File menu. Once you've tinkered a little bit and gotten everything how you want it, you can save the current export settings as default so you don't have to do it every time you save a figure. This is done on the bottom of the same menu 'Export Styles --> Save as style named:' --> choose "default" and click 'Save'.

[Here](http://dgleich.github.io/hq-matlab-figs/) are some more good tips for saving nice figures in MATLAB:

Comment: thank you , but does the print option already save the image or I should use save afterwards again ? and what does gcf mean ?

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti The `print` command does the saving for you. `gcf` gets the _current_ figure, e.g. if you have more than one figure open, `gcf` gets the most recently active one. See more here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcf.html

Comment: I found a limit of dpi at `9000`