# How to adjust spacing between subplots in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, subplot

How to reduce/modify spacing between subplots in MATLAB?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`subplot_tight()`](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30884-controllable-tight-subplot) function by Nicolay S. available at FileExchange. You can use it as a substitute for matlabs `subplot()` function (first syntax example) or add margins argument to define exactly the space used by your subplot (second syntax example)

```
h=subplot_tight(m, n, p);
h=subplot_tight(m, n, p, margins);
```

The argument `margins` is a two elements vector [vertical,horizontal] defining the margins between neighbouring axes. Default value is 0.04.

Comment: This is absolutely which I wanted. Thanks @Georg W.

Comment: @George, this is exactly the same suggestion as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16410645/3978545) linked from the question I marked as duplicate an hour before you answered. If a question is marked as duplicate (and you agree, which is clear in this case) then it's better to also flag as duplicate or leave it all together. In particular, this question is *really* poorly formed - 9 words and a picture is a low quality question and answering will only encourage future low quality questions.